# Create wifi hotspot using a HSPA dongle

Tags: 12.04, wireless, hot-spot

I have 12.04 (LTS)

I know how to create a wifi hotspot using a wired connection.
But when I create the HSPA dongle, the connection is created using an external application and doesn't use eth0 or the wifi adapter. So I am not sure how to create a wifi hotspot using the dongle?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this:

- [How To Set Up A Wireless Hotspot (Access Point Mode) That Supports
  Android In Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html)

Once installed simply run:

`sudo ap-hotspot start`

Also take a look at this tutorial:

- [Making a WiFi Hotspot / Access Point using Linux & wifi lan card/USB
  adapter](http://exain.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/making-a-wifi-hotspot-access-point-using-linux-wifi-lan-cardusb-adapter/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is also a [Debian tutorial](http://agentoss.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/creating-a-wireless-access-point-with-debian-linux/) in setting up a wifi hot spot
   that could be of help.
2. If you have **wine** on your Ubuntu distro installed you could try running this windows
   program [my public wifi](http://www.mypublicwifi.com/publicwifi/en/index.html)  i used it on my windows PC and it
   worked perfect
3. If you really stuck id suggest installing a virtual box and then
   running a windows OS inside the virtual box and installing my public WiFi